# Can you buy a property after being sent by a chance card?

Tags: monopoly

Imagine I roll the dice and land on a chance card space. The chance card sends me forward to a property space. Can I buy it?

I haven't been able to find a clear straight answer to this question online nor in the rulebook.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. From [the official rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf), "whenever you land on an unowned property you may buy that property from the Bank at its printed price."

Comment: It's worth noting that if a chance card sends you to a property someone else owns you will owe them rent.

Answer (score 7):

If you end up on a property as the result of a Chance card, the result is the same as if you had landed on it through the roll of the dice. "If it is unowned, you may buy it from the bank," is what the card will often say.

If it is owned, you must pay rent (unless it is mortgaged). Sometimes the chance card will specify a "double" or higher than usual rent (e.g. ten times the dice instead of four times for a single owned utility).